# Is E=hf applicable for all types of particle?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

According to Planck's law, E=hf is applicable for photon and photon shows wave-particle duality. But De Broglie proved that Electron and other substances also shows wave-particle duality and he showed that
lambda=h/p. But I have some problem about this topic. This is: mc^2=hf or, mc^2=hc/lambda or, mc=h/lambda or, lambda=h/mc. But the term 'mc' is the momentum of photon but not the momentum of other dynamic substance. So how lambda=h/mc=h/p shows the wavelength of any substance? Isn't Planck's law E=hf applicable for other substance except photon?

Answer (score 0):

The momentum of a photon is not given by

$$p = \frac{h}{mc}$$

since a photon has no mass. Instead momentum of a photon is given by

$$p = \frac{E}{c}$$

where $E$ is the energy of the photon (and this equation applies to other massless particles). The de Broglie wavelength of a particle with mass $m$ and velocity $v$ is given by

$$\lambda = \frac{h}{p} = \frac{h}{mv}$$

And the equation $E = hf$ applies to photons and all fundamental particles (and certain composite particles).

Comment: But if E=hf can be applied for all particle, the De Broglie wavelength should be λ=hv/mc. Because, mc^2=hf implies mc^2=hc/λ implies mc=h/λ implies m=h/λc and thus we get p=hv/mc. So if E=hf can be applicable for other particle except photon, then De Broglie wavelength should not be applied to other particles except photon. So what is the solution of this case?

Comment: @Md.HasibulHossain $E=\sqrt{(m_0c)^2+(pc)^2}$ since photons are massless that's why E=pc for photon.